# How to permanently set path in Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: command-line

I executed.

```
export PATH=/home/varun/SOFTWARE/MOLDEN/molden5.1:$PATH
```

In my terminal; followed by `which molden`

I get the expected output:`/home/varun/SOFTWARE/MOLDEN/molden5.1/molden`

But this is temporary. When I close my terminal `which molden` does not give me any response. What should I do? Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, modifying your `$PATH` in that way is a temporary change for your current terminal session.  Other concurrent or later terminal sessions will not see that change reflected.  Add that [command to your `~/.profile` file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path) if you want it to persist.

Secondly the `which` command is designed to search the directories in your `$PATH`.  If the link to "molden" is not in your `$PATH` or (in your case) your `$PATH` gets reverted, it will not find it.  See the `which` [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/which) for more details.

Comment: You can also note that, at the bottom of `.profile`, it adds `$HOME/bin` to your path if `$HOME/bin` exists. You can copy and paste that at the bottom and replace both `bin`s in the copy with `SOFTWARE/MOLDEN/molden5.1/`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ubuntu Desktop (GUI), and you modify `~/.profile`, you still won't see the changes reflected in a new graphical/Gnome Terminal because it starts the Terminal as a non-login shell, so it doesn't load `~/.profile`. You will have to log out and log back in for it to take effect.

An alternative is to set the path in `~/.bashrc`, which is loaded for non-login shells. Then new graphical/Gnome Terminals will reflect the change. This isn't the canonical method, but you won't have to log out and back in.